# Unique Constraint with Composite Keys in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constraints, composite-key

I have an entity with two foreign keys that i also want to use as constraint
is there any way in JPA to define a constraint that will only be unique if the 
same **FROM_CURRENCY_ID** and **TO_CURRENCY_ID** are repeated but allows if values
for reversed for **FROM_CURRENCY_ID** and **TO_CURRENCY_ID**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CURRENCY_CONVERSION")
public class CurrencyConversion extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2440725717151990999L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FROM_CURRENCY_ID")
    private Currency fromCurrencyId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TO_CURRENCY_ID")
    private Currency toCurrencyId;

    @Column(name = "CURRENCY_RATE", nullable = false)
    private Double rate;
    // getter setters

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a unique constraint definition to `@Table` annotation

```
@Table(
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"column_1", "column_2"})
)
```